# Find hours between post_date and post_date_gmt

Tags: php, functions, date-time

I'd like to find the time difference -preferably in hours- between post_date and post_date_gmt.

I tried `$age = date_diff(get_post_time(),get_post_time($gmt = true));`

but this returns

`Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, int given in C:\xampp\htdocs\t\wp-content\themes\i\single.php on line 23`

I didn't really understand the official WP documentation on this function -do they refer to just "time" or "timestamps"?

The basic reason is that I abused the post_date to store the last update date while the gmt field still contains the original publication date. I know that's wrong but I needed a quick and dirty solution some time ago for a different problem.

Comment: So is your ultimate goal to display `post_date_gmt` in your site's timezone?

Comment: No. The difference between these 2 timestamps tells me if a post was updated or just published. If the difference is less than 24 hours, it's never been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is check the difference, rather than display or modify anything, then you don't need to do anything complicated with `date_diff()`. All you need to do is compare the number of seconds returned by `get_post_time()` for each date.

`get_post_time()` returns the [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for the date, which is simply the number of seconds since January 1 1970. So if the difference between the two timestamps is greater than 86400 seconds, the difference is greater than 24 hours.

```
$difference = get_post_time( 'U', true ) - get_post_time( 'U', false );

if ( $difference > DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
    // GMT date is over 24 hours more than post date.
}
```

The 'U' in this code tells `get_post_time()` to return the value as a Unix timestamp. It's the default value, but we need to set it to be able to set the second argument, which tells it whether to use the `post_date` or `post_date_gmt`.

In this example `DAY_IN_SECONDS` is a [WordPress constant](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API#Using_Time_Constants) equal to `86400`. Using it makes the code more readable, and you don't have to figure out what the number was supposed to mean later.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! The whole thing is working perfectly and your explanation is much more helpful than the official documentation!